# How to save the previous page to redirect the user back to, that is reliable?

Tags: php, redirect, back

I have seen all the threads on here to find some suggestions on a reliable way to send the user back to the previous page but none answered my question. I tried these two ways:

This one is said to have some vulnerabilities that can be exploited and it doesn't (always) work with HTTPS.

```
$test;
if (empty($test))
{
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
}
```

Then I tried this using JavaScript, which also shouldn't (always) work in incognito mode (but it does for me) and some people has it turned off.

```
$test;
if (empty($test))
{
    echo
    '<script>
    window.onload = function myFunction() {window.history.go(-1);}
    </script>';
    exit();
}
```

I'm wondering what could be a way to do it in a way that always work no matter what? An example would be appreciated!

P.S: please bear in mind that this code is just for demonstration as I don't have a full website or anything, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: A possible approach: Create a cookie say `lastpage` on loading the page, containing the value of `current url` . Then when user moves to other page access this cookie and send back. You may create array of some last locations. (cookie must be accessible to other pages so set the `path` that way)

Comment: Yeah, none of those options are going to work all the time. However, if you need to go back on your own PHP website then you can remember the previous page in a PHP session variable, and go back that way. A session doesn't require a cookie, since they can also be blocked.

Comment: @ShivCKushawah Do you have an example of how to do that? It sounds like a solid idea.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware An example on how to do that would be very appreciated!

Comment: Do you know anything about sessions? That's where you have to start: [PHPsessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). I also like this article: [How to Create Bulletproof Sessions](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions). Once you know about sessions this problem is easy to solve, you don't need an example for that. You cannot boil an egg without first learning something.

Comment: @KIKO Software Sessions could be used but It may not work if user closes browser and re-opens the webpage. It will not work in all `circumstances`

Comment: @ShivCKushawah There is also not really any previous page after the browser was closed. But you're right, sessions rely on a url query parameter if no cookie can be stored, and closing the browser would probably wipe it.